# Realloc arguments vector and string manipulation

Tags: c, shell, unix, environment-variables, malloc

I am asked to implement a reduced system shell that needs to be coded in C, and I have to achieve some of the features of an UNIX shell.

One of them is the replacement of `~[USER]` to USER home dir, if USER appears, or the default environment variable "HOME" if it doesn't. I could write the code that iterates all over the commands (i.e. "ls ~hxshfx | sort | echo $var" -> argvv = {ls ~hxshfx, sort, echo $var}, but I can't figure out what to code if I want to change the own argvv value (i.e, ls /home/hxshfx | sort | echo a). I know I should use realloc but I don't understand how to use it when no malloc has been called. I do have another if statement for variables like `$VAR` but the problem is the same, the reallocation of information at `argvv[i][j]` position.

This is my code snippet:

```
void metacharacters (char *** argvv) {
    int i, j;
    char user, var, * aux, * toSubstitute, * name;
    user = '~';
    var = '$';
    for (i = 0; argvv[i] != NULL; i++) {
        for (j = 0; (aux = argvv[i][j]) != NULL; j++) {
            if (aux[0] == user) {
                struct passwd * pswd;
                if (strlen(aux) > 1) {
                    name = (char *) struct passwd * pswd;malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(aux)-1));
                    strncpy(name, aux + 1, strlen(aux)-1);
                    pswd = getpwnam(name);
                    toSubstitute = pswd -> pw_dir;
                    free(name);
                } else {
                    toSubstitute = getenv("HOME");
                }

                // TODO changes to argvv[i][j]

            } else if (aux[0] == var) {
                name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(aux)-1));
                strncpy(name, aux + 1, strlen(aux)-1);
                toSubstitute = getenv(name);

                // TODO changes to argvv[i][j]

                free(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing I don't know how to solve is the shell function "set". When the shell recieves, i.e., "set myvar 1" it should use putenv to set the environment variable "myvar". I do think my function used to set the variable works okay:

```
void setVariable (char * arg1, char * arg2) {
    int ret;
    char * command = strdup(arg1);
    strcat(command, "=");

    strcat(command, arg2);
    // i.e., at this point, command = "myvar=1", since arg1 = myvar; arg2 = 1

    ret = putenv(command);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("putenv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s=%s\n", arg1, getenv(arg1));

    // I do think it works because getenv(arg1) works fine

    free(command);
}
```

But, in the next iteration (or just outside the function setVariable), if I check what is the value of the environment variable "myvar", I always got null, no matter what. Also, if I print all the environment variables, there is no entry with "myvar" name, which is strange since, in the setVariable function, I had getenv(name) and that goes OK.

Thank you.

Comment: With `char * command = strdup(arg1);` you allocate just enough memory to hold the string, you can't append to the result because it won't fit.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that, I now used realloc to increase the memory allocated to hold all the string, but the call getenv outside the function is still giving out null.

Comment: Note that `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, which is often useful as the base/root allocation path.

Comment: When should I use that statement? I don't think it's useful for the getenv/putenv conflict.